# Toggle showing of modified files in the explorer

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Is there a shortcut or functionality in Visual Studio Code which allows us to toggle the showing of modified files?

In Visual Studio Code, it highlights all the files that were created, changed or deleted so I'm thinking if there's a functionality to show only those files so we can quickly access these files from the explorer inside of navigating the whole project.

Comment: So you want to see only modified files in "Explorer" view instead of the whole directory tree? Why not just use the "Source Contol" tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can only show modified files but you can sort all the files so that it puts the modified files at the top of their respective folders.

> // Controls sorting order of files and folders in the explorer. In
>   addition to the default sorting, you can set the order to 'mixed'
>   (files and folders sorted combined), 'type' (by file type), 'modified'
>   (by last modified date) or 'filesFirst' (sort files before folders).

```
  "explorer.sortOrder": "modified",
```

However, that is only within their folders so you still have to go to each folder so it still takes some work.

Of course, your `source control` button will show only modified files.

Comment: The source control button was enough. Thanks!